# Openbox. Open different firefox profiles in specific workspaces

Tags: linux, firefox, startup

I need something like this when I start my openbox session:

```
firefox -p Profile 1 #Open in workspace 4
firefox -p profile 2 #Open in workspace 5
```

But all solutions that I've found uses the *Windows Name* parameter, and that doesn't work very well. (I've tried modifying my openbox's `rc.xml` and using `wmctrl` and a couple other solution, but all in vain)

Is there a direct solution for my problem? Thank you!

Comment: For example, setting rc.xml to: <application class="Firefox*">
   <desktop>2</desktop>
</application> Won't work, because different profiles have the same class. ( http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Applications )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE EDITED ANSWER**

This is rather ugly maybe but I tried it and it seems to work...
It is a lil bit complicated tho...or what do you think?
"sleep" is needed because it needs to time to launch the searchquery so that the title gets set :)

1.Search-query version:

```
#!/bin/bash

firefox -P test1 --new-instance --search "profile1" &
firefox -P test2 --new-instance --search "profile2" &
sleep 3;

#profile1 to desktop 0
wmctrl -r "profile1" -t 0

#profile2 to desktop 1
 wmctrl -r "profile2" -t 1
```

2.Using xdotool:

```
#!/bin/bash

temp="";
pid="";

firefox -P test1 --new-instance &
firefox -P test2 --new-instance &
sleep 1;

#profile1 to desktop 0
pid=`ps aux | grep test1 | awk '{print $2}' | head -1`
temp=`xdotool search --all --pid $pid | tail -n -1`
xdotool set_desktop_for_window $temp 0

#profile2 to desktop 1
pid=`ps aux | grep test2 | awk '{print $2}' | head -1`
temp=`xdotool search --all --pid $pid | tail -n -1`
xdotool set_desktop_for_window $temp 1
```

Comment: I tried this way, but it doesn't work. They opened in the same workspace

Comment: The only this works is if I wait a couple seconds for firefox to open, and then change workspace and open a different firefox profile

Comment: I made an update. What do you think about this solution?

Comment: So reading your previous comment, @rubensoleao , I somewhat get the picture that the solutions in my post above is something you already tried. Am I right? :)

Comment: Yes it is :). t I've dug a bit deeper and this really seams to be the only way to do it! There is a window matching utility named Devil's pie (http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie/ ) and it may work, but for me it's too much hassle. Thanks for the help!